# Which versions of Plone can plone.outputfilters be used safely with?

Tags: plone

I'm writing a Plone product where I'd like to modify the HTML output by richtext fields between its being authored and being shown to a user---in a way similar to the existing transforms applied such as updating the resolveuid links inserted by Kupu/TinyMCE are updated before being shown to a user.

For this, [plone.outputfilters](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.outputfilters/) looks perfect. However, the site this is for is Plone 4.0, and I'm not sure that it's safe for use in versions of Plone prior to 4.1.

Is plone.outputfilters safe for use in Plone 4.0.x? If not, is there a standard way to inject my own transform (it looks like I could take a similar approach to plone.outputfilters)?

**Update**: On Giacomo's advice, I have tried this out in a development Plone 4.0.10 instance and it appears to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a rapid peek to the product's [code](https://github.com/plone/plone.outputfilters) it seems safe for Plone 4.0.x. Looking at the Changelog ("*Respect implementation differences in Python 2.4 and Python 2.6*")  one could say that it's also Plone 3.x compatible, so I'm quite confident that you won't have troubles.

Anyway a more efficient approach to your task would have been to test that product in a development environment  first and then ask for help on specific errors because in 90% of cases if the product can be added to your buildout without throwing exceptions then it's compatible.

Comment: Great and thanks, I'll bear that in mind; it's a lesson I need to learn!

Answer (score 2):

I took care to make it work with Plone 3 when I first wrote it. I haven't been keeping close tabs on it since then. But the test coverage is pretty good, so try running the tests for starters.

Comment: Thanks David. I took Giacomo's advice and tried it out. It seems to work well. Great example filter in the resolveuid/captioning filter too.